# macOS上で等幅フォントでのテキストの描画サイズ

Tags: c++, qt, macos

macOS、C++、Qt5でGUIアプリを作っています。等幅フォントを指定してテキストを描画します。このとき、半角10文字より全角5文字の方が実際に描画されるサイズが短くなります。

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setFont(QFont("Monaco", 20));
    p.drawText(0, 30, "WWWWWWWWWW");
    p.drawText(0, 60, "||||||||||");
    p.drawText(0, 90, "あああああ");
    qDebug() << p.fontMetrics().size(0, "WWWWWWWWWW").width();
    qDebug() << p.fontMetrics().size(0, "||||||||||").width();
    qDebug() << p.fontMetrics().size(0, "あああああ").width();
}
```

[image: テキストの描画]

上記の例では、半角10文字の幅が120px、全角5文字の幅が100pxとして描画されます。
半角10文字と全角5文字が同じ幅で描画されるようにする方法はないでしょうか？

なお、Windowsで同じことを行うと、期待通りのサイズで描画されます。

Comment: 日本語用フォントを使った場合はどうですか(Osakaなど)。Monacoは欧文フォントなので日本語の部分が代替化(他のフォントに自動的に置き換えられる)されている可能性が排除できません。

Comment: Osakaには「レギュラー」と「レギュラー-等幅」があって、後者を使うと期待通りの結果になりました。しかし、プログラムでOsaka等幅を選択する方法がわからず、Qiitaにあった記事を参考に、`Font Book.app` で「"Osaka"を使用停止」の設定をする必要がありました。設定を変えずに、プログラム内の指定でOsaka等幅フォントを選択できればいいのですが。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。

Uncle-Keiさんからいただいたコメントのように、日本語対応の等幅フォントである Osaka を使用するのですが、Osakaには「レギュラー」と「レギュラー-等幅」があって、後者を選択するために一工夫が必要でした。

修正前

```
p.setFont(QFont("Monaco", 20));
```

修正後

```
QFont font = QFontDatabase().font("Osaka", "Regular-Mono", 20);
p.setFont(font);
```

「レギュラー-等幅」のフォントを作成するため、`QFontDatabase`クラスを利用して、`Regular-Mono`を明示的に指定することで、目的のフォントを取得することができました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考： https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41487